Why the exhaust pressure should be equal to ambient pressure? (Part 2)
I'm asking a follow-up question to J. Pipiskin's post: Why the exhaust pressure should be equal to ambient pressure?.
TRF's answer shows a plot of normalized thrust vs exhaust-to-ambient pressure ratio. However, when I try to replicate my own plot in MATLAB, I get the complete opposite result; the thrust shows as being a minimum when the exhaust pressure $p_e$ matches the ambient pressure $p_a$, or $p_e/p_a = 1$. Here's what my graph looks like:

Here's my MATLAB code:
clc; clear; close all;

gam = 1.2;
coef = 2*gam^2/(gam-1)*(2/(gam+1))^((gam+1)/(gam-1));
pa_p0 = 1/100;
pe_pa = linspace(0.1,10,10000);
Ae_Astar = 11.871;

maxThrust = sqrt(coef.*(1 - (pa_p0).^((gam-1)/gam)));
thrust = sqrt(coef.*(1 - (pa_p0.*pe_pa).^((gam-1)/gam))) + pa_p0.*(pe_pa - 1).*Ae_Astar;

figure(1)
plot(pe_pa,thrust./maxThrust)
grid on
xscale log
xlabel('Exhaust-to-Ambient Pressure Ratio, P_e/P_a')
ylabel('Normalized Thrust, F/F_{max}')

I used $\gamma = 1.2$, $p_a/p_0 = 0.01$, and $A_e/A^* = 11.871$. I got the area ratio assuming perfect expansion per $p_e/p_0 = 0.01$ and then plugging in the values using the NASA tool: Rocket Thrust Summary. The thrust expression I wrote in my code is referenced from the Mechanics and Thermodynamics of Propulsion (2nd Ed.) textbook by P. Hill and C. Peterson, Equation \eqref{eq:11.7} on Page 516:

$$\frac{\mathscr{T}}{A^{*}p_0} = \sqrt{\frac{2\gamma^2}{\gamma-1}\left(\frac{2}{\gamma+1}\right)^{(\gamma+1)/(\gamma-1)}\left[1-\left(\frac{p_e}{p_0}\right)^{(\gamma-1)/\gamma}\right]}+\left(\frac{p_e}{p_0}-\frac{p_a}{p_0}\right)\frac{A_e}{A^{*}}\tag{11.7}\label{eq:11.7}$$

I rearranged the equation so that I can calculate the thrust by sweeping the $p_e/p_a$ ratio. The thrust I computed is dimensionless because it is normalized with $A^*p_0$. Then I normalized the thrust values by the max thrust, which I presume from common logic to be derived when $p_e = p_a$, so the pressure thrust term gets neglected. The $A^*p_0$ term gets cancelled out when taking the thrust ratios, so this should yield $\dfrac{F}{F_{\text{max}}}$.
Am I missing anything with these results? Why does my thrust curve look different from TRF's graph?
These results do not make any sense at all because clearly it can be shown how thrust is maximized when $p_e = p_a$, according to this explanation by JoshTheEngineer: Explained: Maximum Thrust Nozzle Exit Pressure Condition.

Never mind I figured out my mistake! I was supposed to make the area ratio vary accordingly with the pressure ratio (per the isentropic relation), so $\frac{A_e}{A^*}$ does not stay fixed. Here is my new corrected code and thrust curve:
clc; clear; close all;

gam = 1.2;
coef = 2*gam^2/(gam-1)*(2/(gam+1))^((gam+1)/(gam-1));
pa_p0 = 1/100;
pe_pa = linspace(0.1,20,10000);
Ae_Astar = (((gam+1)/2)^(1/(gam-1)).*(pa_p0.*pe_pa).^(1/gam).*sqrt((gam+1)/(gam-1).*(1-(pa_p0.*pe_pa).^((gam-1)/gam)))).^(-1);

maxThrust = sqrt(coef.*(1 - (pa_p0).^((gam-1)/gam)));
thrust = sqrt(coef.*(1 - (pa_p0.*pe_pa).^((gam-1)/gam))) + pa_p0.*(pe_pa - 1).*Ae_Astar;

figure(1)
plot(pe_pa,thrust./maxThrust)
grid on
xscale log
xlabel('Exhaust-to-Ambient Pressure Ratio, P_e/P_a')
ylabel('Normalized Thrust, F/F_{max}')


I got the area ratio expression from a worked example I found online for calculating the nozzle optimum expansion ratio: https://www.nakka-rocketry.net/articles/noz_example3.pdf.
Now my graph looks very similar to TRF's!
